# Cannot compile bold text with specified font

Tags: xetex, bold, ubuntu, linux, nimbus-font

I'm trying to do a title page so I can reuse it for multiple works in my University. I'm obligated to use Times New Roman (which explains the usage of Nimbus Roman as an alternative). It almost works, but I can't apply bold text and I don't know why. I'm compiling it with Xelatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, english,]{article}                                                                                                                                                                 
\usepackage[                                                                                                                                                                                  
        a4paper,                                                                                                                                                                              
        left=3cm,                                                                                                                                                                             
        top=4cm,                                                                                                                                                                              
        right=2.5cm,                                                                                                                                                                          
        bottom=2.5cm                                                                                                                                                                          
        ]{geometry}                                                                                                                                                                           
\usepackage{fontspec}                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                       
\setmainfont{Nimbus Roman}                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                              
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                              
        \centering                                                                                                                                                                            
        \textbf{UNIVERSITY NAME IN BOLD TEXT}                                                                                                                                                    
        \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                                                                                                                        
        {\scshape My Name\par}                                                                                                                                                 
        \vspace{3.5cm}                                                                                                                                                                        
        {\huge\bfseries Title\par}                                                                                                                                                    
        \vfill                                                                                                                                                                                
        {City/State\par                                                                                                                                                                       
        2022}                                                                                                                                                                                 
\end{document}
```

Running `$fc-list | grep -i "nimbus"` returns:

```
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Italic.otf: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021024l.pfb: Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Medium Italic
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Regular.otf: Nimbus Sans:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique.otf: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Regular.t1: Nimbus Sans:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021004l.pfb: Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Medium
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.otf: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb: Nimbus Mono L:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-BoldOblique.otf: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-BoldOblique.t1: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Bold.otf: Nimbus Sans:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Italic.t1: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.t1: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSans-BoldItalic.otf: Nimbus Sans:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021023l.pfb: Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Regular Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019063l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Condensed Italic
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Regular.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Bold.otf: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Bold
**/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Bold.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold**
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Bold.t1: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019064l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Italic.t1: Nimbus Roman:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Italic.otf: Nimbus Sans:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022023l.pfb: Nimbus Mono L:style=Regular Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Regular.t1: Nimbus Roman:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.otf: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Regular.otf: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019043l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Condensed
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.t1: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSans-BoldItalic.t1: Nimbus Sans:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Bold.t1: Nimbus Sans:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019044l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.t1: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb: Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Bold.otf: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Bold.t1: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique.t1: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019023l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Italic.t1: Nimbus Sans:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Bold.t1: Nimbus Mono PS:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022004l.pfb: Nimbus Mono L:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019024l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019004l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022024l.pfb: Nimbus Mono L:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Regular.t1: Nimbus Sans Narrow:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Italic.otf: Nimbus Roman:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019003l.pfb: Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular
```

As far as I understand, shouldn't `/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Bold.t1: Nimbus Roman:style=Bold` be the desired font? But the log file says I don't have a bold font for the specified Font family:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NimbusRoman(0)' created for font 'Nimbus    
(fontspec)             Roman' with options [Ligatures=TeX].    
(fontspec)                  
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS    
(fontspec)             series/shapes:    
(fontspec)                  
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Nimbus    
(fontspec)             Roman/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"    
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:     
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Nimbus    
(fontspec)             Roman/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"    
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:     
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Nimbus    
(fontspec)             Roman/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"    
    
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Since you're using XeLaTeX, can't you use just the real Times New Roman font? It's directly usable, even in Linux (worst case scenario, you just need to dump the TTF file into /usr/share/fonts).

Comment: As a linux user myself, I would resist using the "real" Times New Roman as well. TeX Gyre Termes (newtxtext/newtxmath packages for pdflatex or loaded directly) is a more up to date version of the same Nimbus Roman font/Times clone; I would try using that first. The XITS/STIX fonts are also Times clones.

Comment: @frabjous, yes TeX Gyre Termes does work, but I'm still interested in an explanation for the issue. Didn't know it was more up to date, thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem and was unable to. My linux distro's package manager won't let me have the opentype and type1 versions installed at the same time. I suspect your problem has something to do with that. If I use the opentype versions, your code works for me as is. If I use the type1 versions, I just need to change 'Nimbus Roman' to 'Nimbus Roman No9 L' with `\setmainfont` but then it works fine. (I'd use the opentype versions with xelatex.) Your versions seem different, and I don't know how you installed them.